# How to optimize Spark RDD operations loop?

Tags: java, apache-spark

How to optimize the RDD operations performed in a loop?

For example:

```
  for(String x:mycollection) {
//Perform something on RDD with x
}
```

> Problem:

Above code performs the RDD operation on each element sequentially even though there is no dependency on each collection item.

Can this be optimized to perform RDD operation on each element in parallel?

Will Java reflections help in this regard?

Comment: You can use the asyncActions for concurrency and also use FAIR scheduler for more details check this blog may be it will help https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/10/21/demystifying-asynchronous-actions-in-spark/

Comment: In the example above, is `mycollection` an RDD ? or is it a local collection?